# C#, Winforms automation app throwing 0x800AC472 error when saving excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, export-to-excel

I am writing a winform app that reads data from an sql database, paste it into excel and then saves the file in a given location.

My current issue is i'm encountering system error : 0x800AC472 when saving down the excel file.

So far I have tried adding

```
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

to the on click method, after calling the excel save function.

From my googling it seems as though it may be due to the COM object not being removed after usage? these GC methods were meant to clear this, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. The reason I think it's not working properly is that there is still a microsoftoffice.exe process running in task manager after executing the code and receiving the error.

Something else worthy of mention is that if i wrap the code in a try-catch, the error is pasted to the console and the excel file is saved without issue, the only issue being that the process is still running in the task manager.

Is anyone here able to help me isolate the issue in my code causing this error? Thank you.

Here is the code that is called upon button press;

```
else if (((DataGridView)sender).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Run")
                    {
                    // return SQL into datatable
                    var returnedDT = SQLAcess.SQLtoDataTable(dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()!);

                    //find item to open
                    string loadstring = DataGridClass.CellColumn(dataGridView1, "Load_Location", e.RowIndex);

                    //finds workbook to paste into.
                    var SettingsDataset = XMLData.ReturnXMLDataset(2);       
                    var workbookstring = XMLData.returnXMLcellwithcolumnname(SettingsDataset, "Data_Dump_Worksheet_name", e.RowIndex);

                    //find location to save it
                    string savestring = DataGridClass.CellColumn(dataGridView1, "Save_location", e.RowIndex);

                    //execute export to excel, with the locations saved from above.
                    GXOMIClassLibrary.My_DataTable_Extensions.ExportToExcelDetailed(returnedDT, loadstring, workbookstring, savestring);
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    }
```

The
`GXOMIClassLibrary.My_DataTable_Extensions.ExportToExcelDetailed(returnedDT, loadstring, workbookstring, savestring);`
method refers to a class library I have created with this method below;

```
public static void ExportToExcelDetailed(this System.Data.DataTable DataTable, string ExcelLoadPath, string WorksheetName, string ExcelSavePath)
        {
            try
            {
              
                int ColumnsCount;

                //if datatable is empty throw an exception.
                if (DataTable == null || (ColumnsCount = DataTable.Columns.Count) == 0)
                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

                // load excel, and create a new workbook
                //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                //Excel.Workbooks.Add();

                var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelLoadPath);

                //TELL THE PROGRAM WHAT WORKBOOK TO OPEN
                // select the right worksheet.
                var Worksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[WorksheetName];
              
                // DataCells
                int RowsCount = DataTable.Rows.Count;
                object[,] Cells = new object[RowsCount, ColumnsCount];

                for (int j = 0; j < RowsCount; j++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                        Cells[j, i] = DataTable.Rows[j][i];

                //find last row
                var xlRange = (Excel.Range)Worksheet.Cells[Worksheet.Rows.Count, 1];
                long lastRow = (long)xlRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
                long newRow = lastRow + 1;

                ///cells[2,1] needs to become cell below last paste
                Worksheet.Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[newRow, 1]), (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[newRow + RowsCount -1, ColumnsCount])).Value = Cells;


                // check fielpath
                if (ExcelSavePath != null && ExcelSavePath != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Worksheet.SaveAs(ExcelSavePath);
                        excelApp.Quit();
                       // Worksheet.Close(0);
                        //richTextBox1("Excel file saved!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                            + ex.Message);
                        excelApp.Quit();
                    }
                }
                else    // no filepath is given
                {
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                }
                excelApp.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
                
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

changing this part of the ExportToExcelDetailed seems to have corrected the issue;

```
  if (ExcelSavePath != null && ExcelSavePath != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Worksheet.SaveAs(ExcelSavePath);                       
                        excelApp.Quit();
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Worksheet);
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                            + ex.Message);
                        excelApp.Quit();
                    }
                }
                else    // no filepath is given
                {
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                }
```